# Alert after second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have below code:

```
<a href="#" id="@item.Id" name="vote" ><img src="/Content/images/021.png" style="float:left" alt="" /></a>
```

which invokes an ajax call. on the first call. if the return is true, on the second call I want to make an alert box saying you can do vote only once.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("div.slidera_button a").click(function (e) {
            var item = $(this);
            e.preventDefault();
            $.get('@Url.Action("VoteAjax","Home")', { id: item.attr("id") }, function (response) {
                if (response.vote == "false") {
                    alert("foo.");
                } else {
                    //something
                }
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

this works, if i click on the button then refresh the page but it doesnt work, if i try to click twice.

I want to the user to be able to click multiple times and only after first one, they get a popup.

why this is not working?

how can i fix it?

**EDIT: works in FF.. doesnt work in IE.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
a.disabled {
    opacity: 0.5;
    /* whatever other styles you want */
}   
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        $("div.slidera_button a").click(function (e) {
            var item = $(this);
            if (item.hasClass("disabled")) {
                // alert when they vote
                // you'll need to handle some way to add this 
                // server side to account for page reload, yes?
                alert('You may only vote once');
            }
            $.get('@Url.Action("VoteAjax", "Home")'
                , { id: item.attr("id") }
                , function (response) {
                    // if this returns successfully, you voted.
                    item.addClass('disabled');
                }
            });
            return false;
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what s happening is, on the second click, it s not making the ajax call but still have the same response, i got from the first click.

Comment: $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); this did it. if u add it as answer i ll accept. thanks for ur effort.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("div.slidera_button a").live('click',function (e) {
            var item = $(this);
            e.preventDefault();
            $.get('@Url.Action("VoteAjax","Home")', { id: item.attr("id") }, function (response) {
                if (response.vote == "false") {
                    alert("foo.");
                } else {
                    //something
                }
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

Or JQuery Delegate method to trigger this click

Comment: what s happening is, on the second click, it s not making the ajax call but still have the same response, i got from the first click.

Comment: try writing e.preventDefault() function after ajax request *Not Sure it ll work